# Validate <input type="number" /> with AngularJS and Pattern/RegEx

Tags: regex, angularjs

I have a input of type number, and I want to make sure it only accepts a number. I can do this fine on the Server side, but with AngularJS I can not get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
<input type="number" ng-pattern="/[0-9]+/" name="numOfFruits" ng-model="basket.numOfFruits" />
```

I suspect this has something to do with the pattern I am supplying `[0-9]+` basically I only want numbers in this text box, anything that is not made up of the numbers 0 to 9, I want the input invalid.

At the moment, my input field sees this `aa23423` as valid input!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use anchors:

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

- `^`: Start-of-line anchor.
- `[0-9]+` One or more numbers between `0` and `9`.
- `$`: End-of-line anchor.

So this matches the start of the string, then it matches the one or more digits, after that it looks for the end-of-string, so it matches a string containing only numbers and nothing else.

Otherwise, `/[0-9]+/` will match only a part of `aa23423`, more accurately the number `23423` and thus will give you valid.

Comment: @Ciwan Then the problem lies somewhere else, the regular expression is perfectly OK.

Comment: Thanks I too tried your RegEx in a test just now, and it works perfect !! Why is it failing in AngularJS :/

Comment: @Ciwan Unfortunately I don't with AngularJS. I just work with regular expression.

Comment: @Ciwan what version of angular do you use?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I'm using 1.0.7

Comment: @Sniffer it turns out, this issue is a well known bug in AngularJS. Your RegEx is perfecto ;)

Comment: It actually isn't a bug in AngularJS. Some browsers, on `input[type=number]`, will change the value to `''` instead of the actual value if it is not a valid `Number`. So Angular evaluates `''` as `required` being invalid, not Number or your Regex.

Comment: The start and end anchors are actually added by Angular (at least in some cases). As @atdrago pointed out the browser will clear out the value in the input box before Angular sees it. I've also had Angular fill the value back in for me so it weirdly pops out until the control regains focus.

Comment: @RobRussell I haven't used Angular before, so I wouldn't know about that. I only know about regular expressions.

Comment: @Ciwan have you made sure you've added `novalidate` to your containing `form` element?

Answer (score 5):

Here is regexp to validate floating point numbers, both positive and negative:

```
/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/
```

Use this regexp in 'text' input, example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="score" ng-pattern="/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/" required/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pattern don't work for input with `type="number"`.
You can use `type="text"` and than convert value to number

Comment: If what the user inputs is considered a number (as of type="number"), then pattern will catch anything else (i.e. if you specify the length of the string, or if it can contain dots, or not). (tested on Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your regex as a scope variable
In the controller, it worked for me.

Comment: Take a look here at the way integerval is defined: http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/FormValidationUsingAngularJS.html?m=1