# angular ng-pattern is ignored when using type=number

Tags: angularjs

I am not seeing the `ng-invalid` class applied when I type into the field a string like `abc`. The `ng-pattern` works if i test it on the console...but not in angular.

```
<input type="number"
 step=".05"
 ng-pattern="/^\d{0,}\.{0,1}\d{0,}$/"
 ng-model="someNumber">
```

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/rxbmgUHPtNmmZPJsBAOJ?p=preview Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124302/validate-input-type-number-with-angularjs-and-pattern-regex) seems similar, posted yesterday.  No answers yet.  Are you on Angular 1.0.7 as well?

Comment: i'm on 1.0.8 which I thought was the latest stable release.

Comment: @chovy The latest stable version is now 1.2

Comment: still doesn't work for me. neither does your example (chrome)

Comment: it *does* work in Firefox. Must be a angular/chrome bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@musically_ut's plnkr in the comments works for Firefox—i.e. the input element gets class `ng-invalid` for string `abc`—but not for Chrome.

For Chrome, it works for me if I add the `required` attribute, i.e.

```
<input type="number"
       step=".05"
       required
       ng-pattern="/^\d{0,}\.{0,1}\d{0,}$/"
       ng-model="someNumber">
```

Comment: is there a way to allow empty values?

Comment: Hmm, `required` means empty isn't valid, doesn't it? Well, I'm still in the midst of working on the same kind of issues, but so far I seem to be having the validation success you're looking for with changing the type from `number` to `text`. Only downside I see so far is losing the up/down spin buttons (ok for me). I'm still exploring whether I need to have `pattern` in addition to `ng-pattern`, but I'm hoping not as that causes the browser to show its own prompt like "Please match the requested format".

Comment: sure, `required` is ok but when the page loads its empty until the data gets filled in. so it shows as an error, which I want to avoid. Maybe I just make the regex match empty as well.