# Regex in angular- first digit not zero, but allow single zero

Tags: regex, angularjs

I want to have input element which allows one of two conditions:

- Single zero can be entered
- Number with max of 9 digits can be entered, but first digit shouldn't be zero

I wrote this regex (solution works in online regex testers):

```
/(^0$)|(^[1-9]\d{0,8}$)/
```

But when I use it in ng-pattern in Angular, it doesn't work.
Here is my plunker example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/iDQ7ly8ypJ3UmN5A0hJw?p=preview

Not sure if alternation is doing the problems, or I messed up the regex.

UPDATE: it seems that type="number" is causing problems. Unfortunately, I need to have this in my code, so I'm searching for solution which works with type="number".

Comment: fyi, you don't need any of the brackets: `/^0$|^[1-9]\d{0,8}$/` or you could `/^(0|[1-9]\d{0,8})$/`

Comment: You're right, stayed from testing, was frustrated :) But it still doesn't work. For example, it accepts 01 as valid pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. I did the following:

- Took out the `type="number"`.
- Gave the `form` a name.
- Gave the `input` a name.
- Referenced the `form` and `input` via their names instead of their `id` and `ng-model` values, respectively.

It converts the value to a number under the covers, stripping the leading zeros and converting text to 0, etc.. And the `name` is the correct way to access it as far as I can tell.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="myNumberField" ng-model="myNumber" ng-pattern="/(^0$)|(^[1-9]\d{0,8}$)/" required/>
    <span ng-show="myForm.myNumberField.$error.pattern">Invalid pattern</span>
</form>
```

[Here is a plunker for it.](http://plnkr.co/edit/laB3Q7nApuoLT9NYnCGX)

Comment: Basically you removed type="number" from my example. Is that causing problems?

Comment: Works fine for me... I can still type all types of characters in the textbox, but it doesn't convert things to a number under the covers. Your regex validation should be enough for that anyway. And I added a name, which was important because I couldn't access it via the ng-model. Both changes were required.

Comment: [See here for another case of this happening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124302/validate-input-type-number-with-angularjs-and-pattern-regex#comment32363850_20124322)

Comment: If you add type="number" to your code, it still works? Because I've tried both your example and mine, and it doesn't work with type="number".

Comment: No, that's my point @MarkoTošić. My example will not work with `type="number"`. That's why I got rid of it. I don't think there's a way to get this to work with `type="number"`. The browser will do everything it can to convert the value in the textbox to a number before angular gets the chance to check the regex against it.

Comment: Sorry, I also gave the form a name instead of an id so that I could reference it in `ng-show`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm using some directives to calculate some expressions from that input. I guess I'll have to play with directives and convert text to number if I want things to get working.

I will accept your answer, thank you for clarifying the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the acceptance. I hope you get the directive stuff resolved.